# How do I remove bottom padding that appears below a TextBox in Windows Phone when tapped?

Tags: textbox, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, padding

I am attempting to implement a chat view in Windows Phone 8. When a user taps my TextBox at the bottom of my View, the view shifts vertically as the keyboard appears, but an additional amount of padding appears at the bottom of the view. I have seen this happen in other apps as well.

Here is my app:

[image]

Here is an equivalent app (Whatsapp) that has clearly solved the problem.

[image]

Anyone have any ideas on how to correct this issue in a way that won't break my view? My attempts to manually modify padding when Focused/Unfocused have not been successful.

Comment: Have you got ScrollViewer there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news! I have managed to figure out a fix for this. The below code stops the page from being moved up at all and then adds a margin to the bottom of the text box to place it above the keyboard. The value below of 417 seems to work well for me but you can change this to whatever you like. Using this method also stops other content being pushed off screen like the conversation as it will be fully scrollable while the keyboard is active.

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rootFrame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
        rootFrame.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform() { TranslateY = +0 };
        TextInput2.Margin = new Thickness(12, 0, 12, 417);
    }

private void TextBox_LostFocus_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rootFrame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
        rootFrame.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform() { TranslateY = +0 };
        TextInput2.Margin = new Thickness(12, 0, 12, 12);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try  to give bottom margin with negative value. example give -40px and see.

Comment: I looked into this option but the behavior changed from the simulator to my device, and my fear is that an arbitrary constant won't be compatible across devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Grid, set Height to "Auto" where the TextBox is.

Set InputScope="Default".